# RavenDB: How can I prevent high RAM utilization?

Tags: caching, task-parallel-library, ravendb

- My application includes a few queries which return large result sets (although I've capped it with a `Take(300)` lambda.
- During peak usage times, I've seen Raven.Server.exe consume an unusually large amount of RAM.

  - In fact, during these times, Raven.Server.exe can *exhaust* my server's available RAM.

How can I avoid this situation?

- After a few Google searches, I can see that other people have encountered this error before me.
- But RavenDB has evolved during the past few years and there are many configuration *and* code options which can limit the amount of RAM that Raven.Server.exe can consume and disable caching entirely.

Can anyone tell me which options are *most* applicable for my situation?

---

Here is what I found for server configuration options:

- [Link 1](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration)
- [Link 2](http://old.ravendb.net/faq/low-memory-footprint)
- [Link 3](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/ZBXAvLh7yu8/onL_iWZ5dyAJ)

Here is what I found for code options:

- [Link 1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/-b7kTrG-dNo/5NrhpJnddQcJ)
- [Link 2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/KohLTIj6FcU/DqHBUnZ23EcJ)

---

It's clear to me that this [default setting](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration) is not being respected:

> Raven/MemoryCacheLimitMegabytes
>
> The max size in MB for the internal document cache inside RavenDB server. 
>   **Default: 50%** of the total system memory minus the size of the Esent cache.

On my server, with build 2330, without any custom configurations set, Raven.Server.exe was consuming 95% of the available RAM!

---

**EDIT:** I was able to reproduce this in a test environment when executing **only** heavy reads (and no writes).

Comment: You say RavenDB using 95% of your available RAM as if it's a bad thing. It's a server, it's meant to use as much resources as it possibly can consume.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic: Yes. It's a good thing except when RavenDB *exhausts* your server's available RAM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[@Ayende Rahein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15996152/109941) knows infinitely more about RavenDB than I do, but here is what worked for me:

1. `Take(300)` was too much. I needed to change this to `Take(128)` .
2. With a 3.10 GHz quad core client machine, I was peppering a 2.50 GHz single core server with queries inside of a `Parallel.ForEach` loop. I needed to specify the degree of parallelism: `Parallel.ForEach(objects, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 }, currentObject => { /* My Query */ });`
3. I needed to [configure the following options](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/8Pr4fxwzgp4/r28gkyUzmwsJ) on my `DocumentStore` instance:
   `_store.Conventions.DisableProfiling = true;
           _store.Conventions.ShouldCacheRequest = url => false;
           _store.DisableAggressiveCaching();`
4. And in cases where I needed to page my query and make multiple batch requests within a single session, I needed the following:
   `ravenSession.Advanced.Evict(doc); // for  each loaded doc`

I hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: Is there a way to make a session Evict() all documents by default? That would help!

Answer (score 3):

Jim,
Do no assume that this is a cache issue. I would assume it is your indexing. 
Do you have a map/reduce index with multiple from clauses or a SelectMany?

Also, the best place to handle such issues is the mailing list for ravendb.