# RavenDB: How can you force RavenDB to safely release RAM?

Tags: ravendb

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992053/ravendb-how-can-i-prevent-high-ram-utilization)...

If you haven't properly configured RavenDB, it can easily exhaust your server's RAM.

- [Link 1](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ravendb/Ce9oNFD33hI/E6MNHAF_pP4J)
- [Link 2](http://ayende.com/blog/160386/ravendb-2-0-stopship-bug-memory-is-nice-let-us-eat-it-all)
- [Link 3](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/6wVIvApjXMs)

If you've found yourself in this predicament, how can you force RavenDB to **safely** release this RAM?

I thought that recycling the service would do the trick. Unfortunately this corrupted my entire RavenDB installation (fortunately in a test environment). In the Silverlight GUI, RavenDB wasn't even able to retrieve a list of the installed databases; so I wasn't able to see my documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim,
You can ask RavenDB to release memory using:

```
 POST /admin/gc
```

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* recycle the service inside of Server Manager.

Instead, issue the following command in a command prompt in your RavenDB\Server directory:

```
Raven.Server.exe /restart
```

Be patient. It might take a few minutes to restart the service.